Why isn't ~/.config/environment.d/*.conf taking effect?
I created the file ~/.config/environment.d/30-electron-ozone-wayland.conf with these contents:
ELECTRON_OZONE_PLATFORM_HINT=auto

This should set the environment variable ELECTRON_OZONE_PLATFORM_HINT to auto. (In this particular case, it encourages Electron apps to use Wayland if possible.) I then logged out and logged in again.
I opened a terminal and I checked the output of this command:
 $ echo ELECTRON_OZONE_PLATFORM_HINT

However, it did not display auto, instead it printed nothing. How do I ensure that environment.d takes effect?

See the man page for environment.d

It turns out that logging out and logging in again insn't enough for ~/.config/environment.d/*.conf to take effect. Instead, I had to restart the computer.
Also, make sure that the filename ends with .conf
